# Is there a comprehensive list of 语气词 or 语气助词? Or a place I can research more about them?

Tags: grammar, mandarin, vocabulary, usage, meaning-in-context

Is there a comprehensive list of 语气词 or 语气助词? Or a place I can research more about them?

Had an idea to do my dissertation on them but having trouble finding a list of them.

Comment: I guess a list is not enough to buttress your paper. 
Luckily, several tomes are on this subject, like 现代汉语语气词 and 现代汉语虚词例释. If you have no access to these printed books, I highly recommend 现代汉语八百词 which is available in Amazon Kindle shop

Note that 现代汉语八百词 does not have an index of 语气词. It has two indexes, one by pinyin and one by brush strokes. In the brush stroke index, each word is respectively categorized into [连] [副] [名] [助] etc. Each 语气助词 has a [助] attached, like 了[助], 呢[助].

Comment: search web with "语气助词": http://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%AF%AD%E6%B0%94%E5%8A%A9%E8%AF%8D ,borrow from your public or school library:

＂实用现代汉语语法＂（２００１年 北京）第４１０-第４３２页，第三节 语气助词，

Comment: @user6065 thank you a lot this have been very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Modern Chinese / Mandarin:

- 啊 a
- 噢 ao
- 哎 ai
- 唉 ai
- 吧 ba
- 呗 bei
- 哦 o
- 喔 o
- 哈 ha
- 嚯 huo
- 啦 la
- 嘞 lei
- 哩 li
- 啰 luo
- 咯 lo
- 喽 lou
- 咧 lie
- 吗 ma
- 嘛 ma
- 哪 na
- 呐 na
- 哇 wa
- 呦 you
- 哟 yo
- 唷 yo
- 吁 yu

Classic Chinese:

- 呔 dai
- 呵 he
- 乎 hu
- 兮 xi
- 矣 yi
- 也 ye (means: too, also, in modern Chinese)
- 哉 zai

Comment: Is 呀 not counted here?

Comment: @Blaszard This is not a full list, I just collect the common used ones, actually I forgot 呀.